# Where do the prototypes for stream insertion/extraction operator overload functions belong?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Assuming they are not being implemented as `friend` functions.

```
class Foo
{
// in here?
ostream& operator<<( ostream&, const Foo & );
};
```

or

```
class Foo
{
};
// out here?
ostream& operator<<( ostream&, const Foo & );
```

And why?

Comment: The first one won't compile, so the second wins by default.

Comment: Why won't the first one compile?

Comment: When declared as member functions, all binary operator overloads must have only one argument (The implicit `this` parameter is used as the left hand argument).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from Stanley Lippman's ++ primer book:

> When we define an input or output operator that conforms to the conventions of the iostream library, we must take it as a nonmember function.

One option is to declare the overloaded `<<` or `>>` as `friend` function of the class.
The benefit of declaring it as `friend` function is that it can access private parts of your class.

```
class Foo
{
  // in here?
  friend ostream& operator<<( ostream&, const Foo & );
  //^^should not miss this
 };
```

The other option is to overload as `free` function, the canonical way to implement `operator<<` for `Foo` class is this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo & )
{
}
```

This way you cannot directly access private parts of the class, you need to provide some member functions to return internal of your class for printing.

It depends on your application and the second way is usually the `canonical` way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare them either as non-member friend functions or in the surrounding names pace of the Foo. Your first example is missing the key ingredient: friend.

The reason is the way C++ looks for functions (and by that also operators) to call: argument dependent lookup.